# How to create a real-time audio streaming queue?

Tags: node.js, sockets, audio, shoutcast, icecast

So I'm thinking about creating a node application where users can add songs to a "queue" and have the songs be broadcasted to all users in real time, but after looking around I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.

The primary article I read was this one: http://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/streaming-audio-on-the-web-with-nodejs/

It seems like an icecast server could work very well for this, but is there a way for node to push songs to a queue to be played by the icecast server? So far from what I have read it seems the only way to manage songs played is to specify a playlist or add songs manually, and telling the server to not play anything when there are no songs in the queue also seems like a potential issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on a similar project recently. My solution was to use [nodeshout](https://github.com/dgurkaynak/nodeshout) (node binding for libshout) to send audio data from Node to Icecast.

Check out the [streaming example](https://github.com/dgurkaynak/nodeshout/blob/master/demos/stream.js). You can use it like so:

```
function playSong(){
    // Choose next song
    const nextSong = "./song.mp3";
    const fileStream = new FileReadStream(nextSong, 65536);
    const shoutStream = fileStream.pipe(new ShoutStream(shout));

    shoutStream.on('finish',playSong);
}

playSong()
```

This will create a loop and play song after song.

Tip: Increase source timeout in your `icecast.xml` to ~30 seconds. In some cases, with the default, it causes the stream to end, due to songs having a "quick start", where the start of the song has a lower bitrate (to start playing faster).

I've made a Gist with a further example: https://gist.github.com/Cretezy/3623fecb1418e21b5d1f77db50fc7e07